# How do I get text to wrap to not break out of the box using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have HTML elements like this:

```
<li class="store-display-item">
    <div class="store-display-item">
        <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        <p>QuickTrav Carbon Footprint</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Styled like this:

```
.store-display-item
{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.store-display-image
{
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 70px;
}
```

Yet the `<p>QuickTrav Carbon Footprint</p>` renders at nearly 140px, causing my intended adjacent blocks to flow to the next row. How can I get the text to wrap and not exceed the max width of its container?

Comment: Inline elements ignore the `width` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inline is causing it. Remove the class from the inner div, and add the following:

```
.store-display-item div { width: 100px; }

<li class="store-display-item">
    <div>
        <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        <p>QuickTrav Carbon Footprint</p>
    </div>
</li>​
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
.store-display-item p {
    width:100px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Chris Carew  and Mani are both right; it's the display: inline that's causing your width problems (inline elements ignore the width property, as Pumbaa80 stated). If you want to keep the inline behaviour for the li, your css should look something like this:

```
.store-display-item
{
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

li.store-display-item {
    display: inline-block;        
}

.store-display-image
{
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 70px;
}​
```

display: inline-block; will keep the width of the li intact (its computed width is 0 with display: inline).

Further reading:

http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score -2):

I think its because your improper html , you didn't end img with /> try this

```
<li class="store-display-item">
    <div class="store-display-item">
        <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg" />
        <p>QuickTrav Carbon Footprint</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I really don't think that's what's causing it.